Why font issues on different sites with same settings?
We have multiple Websites with the same CSS settings and the sites are on the same server.
So, now the customer says that on Laptop View in Windows Edge, the fonts are pixelated on the first site. But on the other site with the same settings, everything is ok.
Here is the screenshot:

Does anyone know this problem and can help?
I cannot replicate the error - on my devices and browserstack tests, everything is ok.
The font is embed like this:
/* Webfont: AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg */@font-face {
font-family: 'Akzidenz-GroteskBQ';
src: url('AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg.svg#AkzidenzGroteskBQ-Reg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

}
with this details:
font-family: 'Akzidenz-GroteskBQ', sans-serif; 
font-weight: 400; 
font-size: 16px; 
color: #000; 
line-height: 26px;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;


The font-face looks fine. In fact the screenshot doesn't show a pixellated font but rather a weird filtered rendering. You should check the CSS for any applied filters or transforms that may affect the text in an undesired way. It may also be related to an active ie11-compatibility mode in edge (deactivating it might solve the problem). This would at least explain why it happens only on certain pages - edge may apply filters incorrectly when running in compatibility mode or cause script errors. You may ask your clients if they can reproduce this error on another browser e.g firefox.

thanks for your reply. we will check this

Sorry, I missed a point: is this strange rendering reproducible in other Blink/Chromium based browsers (Google Chrome, Brave, Vivaldi Opera)? MS Edge could cover 3 rendering engines: 1. the first iteration (2015) introduced "EdgeHTML" 2. it also supported an ie11 legacy mode (removed in ~2023) 3. 2019: "blink" (also used in all chromium based browsers). While MS discourages the use of these obsolete versions ... some quirky defaults in corporate infrastructure may still enable these exotic legacy settings (some MS certified admins still have a soft spot for ie...).

At least this rendering cannot be explained by errors in @font-face rules - otherwise you would see "Arial". Badly "hinted" fonts would also not explain this result (they would potentially over-emphasize certain stems but not break them). There's a good chance e.g the starting page deploys some filter effects – not properly working in edge-legacy – affecting child text elements. Once you've found the source of the problem, please share your findings with us =)
